# Unity editor connects to firebase but with apk file in oculus I can not connect to firebase

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have been working on connection between google-cloud-firestore to unity. When I run the game in Unity Editor I don't have any problem , but when I build the apk in oculus quest 2 I don't have access to the google-cloud-firestore. It says the database is null! is there anyone who had the same problem?

1. I have tried to donlowad the latest version of firebase sdk for Unity
2. I have added the oculus firebase sample ,
3. I have changed the build to IL2CPP and ARM64 ,
4. I have added keystore and get the SHA certificate fingerprints for firebase .
5. I have added "OVR_SAMPLES_ENABLE_FIREBASE" to scripting define symboles
6. I have changed the internet access to "Require"

Answer (score 0):

I am too stuck on the same issue.

Turns out, Unity SDK for Firebase still has dependencies on Google Play Services, because of which the Singletons wont work

As a workaround you can try - https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/simple-firebase-unity-for-realtime-database-58337